# ASP.NET, URL Rewriting and threads on Linux?

Tags: asp.net, rewrite, mono

Right now converting my normal sql(ite) syntax into compatible MS Server syntax is driving me mad.

My code seems to be mono compatible judging by MoMA. However in global.asax i start several threads in Application_Start to use as a service and excessive url rewrites in Application_BeginRequest (everything is rewriting into default.aspx which calls C# code/class baded on the url). The urls do not have extensions or my have false extentions ie mysite.com/username/page/title.lol - id

I need it all to go to BeginRequest. I also need files to be downloadable. Usually the path will be rewritten as from `/file/user/filename` to `/file/u/s/user/file`. Would this be supported on linux+mono+a good webserver?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apache httpd practically *invented* [URL rewriting](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html).